# Receiving SMS and storing it in database using Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, sms-gateway, twilio-php

i am using Twilio API to send and receive sms from the customers.

Every time i send the sms to my customers, i store the feilds like `to`, `body` in to my database.

I have implemented the API for send message that works fine and am simply saving the fields in to my database.

**My Problem**

When i receive SMS from my customers to my twilio number. i want to get the fields like `from number` and the `body` and save to my databse.

i looked that the documentation here

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/04/get-started-with-twilio-sms-receiving-incoming-sms-quickstart.html

But this only shows how to send a response to customer when a message is received.

I want to save the received sms in to my database.

Can someone help me top get the `from number` and the `message body`  when a SMS is received. tnx..

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of what you have written that isn't working so we can help you debug it?

Comment: If their docs don't help - try checking the value of incoming parameters by getting their test going but logging the value of $_REQUEST. This will show you what fields they may or may not be sending for you to log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for Twilio SMS responses is here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Here is a relevant quote:

> When Twilio receives a message for one of your Twilio numbers it makes
>   a synchronous HTTP request to the message URL configured for that
>   number, and expects to receive TwiML in response. Twilio sends the
>   following parameters with its request as POST parameters or URL query
>   parameters, depending on which HTTP method you've configured.

You should simply have the data fields inside of PHP's `$_REQUEST[]` variable.

`$_REQUEST['MessageSid']` -  A 34 character unique identifier for the message. May be used to later retrieve this message from the REST API.

`$_REQUEST['SmsSid']` -  Same value as MessageSid. Deprecated and included for backward compatibility.

`$_REQUEST['AccountSid']` -  The 34 character id of the Account this message is associated with.

`$_REQUEST['From']` -  The phone number that sent this message.

`$_REQUEST['To']` -  The phone number of the recipient.

`$_REQUEST['Body']` -  The text body of the message. Up to 1600 characters long.

`$_REQUEST['NumMedia']` -  The number of media items associated with your message

Here is an example query you might use with a MySQL database. You should also be sending back a proper TWIXML response to Twilio and scrub the received data before running a query like this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (sid, from, body) 
        VALUES (
                 '".$_REQUEST['MessageSid']."',
                 '".$_REQUEST['From']."',
                 '".$_REQUEST['Body']."'
               )";
```

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilio passes parameters in its HTTP request as form-encoded values, so you just need to use the REQUEST object to grab them:

```
$from = $_REQUEST['From']
```

The [SMS Quickstart for PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/replying-to-sms-messages) has a more detailed example.

Hope hat helps.